# can we keep same password for mysql and for some specific databse?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

we use different password for specific database and for mysql.for instance, say root user password is 'root' and we have database whose password is also 'root', is it possible to use same password?

Comment: Why do hotels use different keys for different rooms? Why not just have the same key?

Comment: They can all be the same if you want - it all depends on what level of security you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same user (same username and password) for all databases all will be compromised if one application is compromised since all applications are able to query data from all databases. Another reason for not using root when connecting from applications is to not have less privileges, like not having ALTER TABLE right, for the application